# Azure Defender for Cloud - AWS Connector: Failed to create security connector

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-defender

We are attempting to set up Azure Defender for Cloud and connect our AWS environment.

We have gone through the AWS account setup wizard and successfully applied the Cloud Formation Template provided.

We have configured for single account and enabled Servers and Databases (with default settings). We have AWS system manager operational on the AWS side.

[Account Details Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dytlv.png)

[Select Plans Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWgTb.png)

Upon submission, the connection process starts but we quickly receive the following error:

```
Failed to create security connector. Error: 'Contract validation of data model failed, with error: The json value of configuration failed validation, with reason: Configuration : Configuration value cannot be null!. ID for failure: 16ecf154-8864-419e-b787-304ddee9b1d9'
```